# MinGW64: make & mingw32-make not working nor found in bin

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64, mingw32

I downloaded the latest version of MinGW64 from Microsoft's setup guide for VS, and both g++/gdb work fine but when I try to use make/mingw32-make I get the same "the term is not recognized" error.

The problem is searching out this error gets me nowhere, there are no updated pages that show how to install/fix the makefile issue.

Does anyone know a workaround for MinGW64?

Comment: Where did you download MinGW-w64 from exactly?
Have you tried the standalone version from https://winlibs.com/? It comes with `mingw32-make`.

Comment: I got it from MSYS2's site directly: https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: Did you use `pacman` to install MinGW-w64 from MSYS2?